# From the results how to find the formula behind a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

From the following table how can I find the formula to reproduce this results, given that X is between the indicated range on the left column?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this define the following function

$$f(x) =  \left\lfloor \frac{x-10}{10 + ( -1)^{g(x)}} \right \rfloor+1$$

Where $g(x)$ values either $0$ or $1$

\begin{cases} 1 &, x\in (10,18) \\ 0 &,x\in (19,29) \\ 1 &, x\in (30,38) \\ \vdots \end{cases}

you can think about the functions in the type of $\lfloor \sin ( x + c \sin x ) \rfloor$. Where the $\lfloor \rfloor$ is the floor function ( greatest integer ). We want a periodic function with unequal interval seizes. Check this 
[Asymmetric periods in a sine curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341764/asymmetric-periods-in-a-sine-curve). Try for example this $$ \operatorname{floor}\left(2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\ +\ \frac{\pi}{4}\sin\left(\frac{x-0.97}{2.6}\right)\right)\right)$$

you need to play with such functions.

Comment: The problem you need to make the seize of intervals a whole number if not then there will be an overlap somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no particular formula of this series**

It just follows a pattern, that's it.

Anyways I can give you a continuation of the pattern.

**In the column X**

You add 8 to every 2n+1 terms for n being a whole number.

You add 10 to every 2n terms for n being a whole number.

Remember to add 1 to the maximum value of the preceding range.

**In Results Column**

You add 1 sequentially for the corresponding X range.